# Tensorflow installation error in Windows 10, 64 bit. Python Version 3.7.1

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to setup tensorflow on my computer which has windows 10, 64 bit and python version 3.7.1, but I get the error message that says "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )..." On checking the tensorflow documentation, I realized that tensorflow has not yet been upgraded to be supported in python 3.7. So, what should I do? What are my options to use tensorflow on my computer. I know I can always uninstall the python and install the 3.6 version. However, that is my last option. 
Help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

I am using the Anaconda distribution and I tried using conda install instead of pip install, and it keeps on loading and won't do anything at all.
I also tried creating a virtual python 3.6 environment in anaconda prompt. It will download the tensorflow then, however, when I go to my jupyter notebook to run the code, it again gives the error saying the package has not been installed.

Comment: Did you activate the env before starting jupyter?

Comment: I did activate the env before starting jupyter.

Comment: Activate first then start jupyter

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I first created the virtual python env and then activated it and used the same anaconda console to start the jupyter notebook. I checked the version of python inside the jupyter notebook. It is still 3.7.1. However, I know the env activation worked fine because when I check the python version in the console itself, it says 3.6.6